# nasm application crash after printf

Tags: assembly, crash, printf, nasm

Very simple Hello world with nasm. I successful assembly it with `nasm.exe main.asm -f win32 -o main.obj` and linking it with `gcc.exe -fno-use-linker-plugin -o main.obj output.exe`
It runs ok, it prints on the screen and then the program crashes (`output.exe has stopped working`). It seems I made some stuff on the stack but I can't find the error. Is it ok if I pass parameters on the stack (stdcall)? It should, because it prints ok but..
Here's the code

```
section .data
    msg db "Hello, world!", 0

section .text
    global _main
    extern _printf
_main:

    push msg
    call _printf

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Platfor: win8.1 x64, Intel CPU, NASM 2.11, GCC latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` being a C function, it isn't `stdcall`, it is `cdecl`. As such, the caller (you) needs to free the argument after the call. Use `add esp, 4`.

Comment: Thanks :) Do I need to free the call for any cdecl calling function?

Comment: Yes, applies to all `cdecl` functions.